# cordova.js(610, 1) Runtime Error in Microsoft JScript: 'cordova' is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm integrating Sencha Touch and PhoneGap, and when it packaged with Cordova framework, to run on an Android emulator, it makes me all right but fails to install the app on the emulator, and command shows me:

```
\android\cordova\lib\cordova.js(610, 1)
Runtime Error in Microsoft JScript: 'cordova' is undefined
```

And in emulator displays the cordova apache with text "Device is reading."

My  index.html (in assets / www);

```
<div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
</div>        

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
```

Please Can you help with what I'm doing wrong? Because not recognize Cordova.js, If is within the code and the project?

Thankss

Comment: What version of cordova do you use? How do you build the app?

Comment: `Runtime Error in Microsoft JScript` sounds like you're trying to execute cordova.js on your computer (or at least a windows device). What steps are you following to start your app?

Comment: Martin, I am using cordova-2.9.0. Thanks

Comment: Steps: Adding app.json phonegap and introduce path tools and windows to android platform-tools, Build the android sencha in android:
 
create buid/sample/android com.sample sample 

Modify build.xml 

<target name="-after-build"> 
   <Delete /> dir="${build.dir}/android/assets/www" 
   <copy todir="${build.dir}/android/assets/www"> 
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}/package"/> 
   </ copy> 
</ target> 

And packaged:

Sencha build app package (Pack App with Sencha) 
build \sample\android\cordova\build - debug (Packs the app Cordova) 
build\sample\android\cordova\run(Install app Android emulator)

Comment: sorry, but I'm new around here, and not format well as my comments. 

Excuse me. Thanks again.

Comment: Just curious: your index.html looks quite different from a index.html created by sencha cmd. Where comes yours from? Sencha uses its microloader to initialize the app, so I am missing something like '<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>'.

Comment: Be shaped by then packed the app with cordova replacing some of the original index, maybe I got confused, I saw many ways to do that saturates me. 

I come from Spain

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are not using Ionic, this tip from their forums is probably what you're looking for:

When you run `cordova platform add android` and then `cordova build android`, cordova.js should be added to your project/platforms/android/assets/www folder.

Source: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-js-in-the-getting-started-tutorial/414

Comment: Thanks for responding and thanks for your link, I'm doing exactly the process well, I have my cordova.js within project / platforms / android / assets / www folder. 

Thanks again for answering